# how do we enforce entry of automation java classes's path in an xml file?

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, build-automation

We have two teams working on quality automation project and we share a module to be  tested. For that purpose we have created an xml file for each team which is read by Jenkins to generate a report that shows success / failure of the test classes that were executed.

We want to ensure that every new java test class created has an entry in the respective xml file so that it is picked up by Jenkins and reported. Not sure how to do this. Any examples or direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Surely there's an automated way to make Jenkins run *all* your tests, would that be acceptable?

Comment: It sounds like an option. However, we are generating team wise reports of test success and failures. If we make Jenkins run all the tests, not sure whether we will be able to distinguish between team specific test failures.